# Comparing relative paths in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, timestamp

I am trying to build a bash script capable of comparing two directories given as arguments $1 and $2, and changing the files' timestamps from the second directory ( if they are not different than a given timestamp $3 ) to be the same as the files with the same name in the first directory. I'm doing okay with that, but I don't see how to access the folders inside the given directories, and compare the files inside those folders.

For example, if I have Directory1 and Directory2 given as arguments:

Directory1 contains:

```
-text.txt
-folder1/secondfile.txt
-folder2/thirdfile.txt
```

and Directory2 contains:

```
-text.txt
-folder1/secondfile.txt
-folder3/thirdfile.txt
```

so in this case I want my script to modify the files text.txt and secondfile.txt, but not the thirdfile.txt because the relative paths are not the same. How would my script access folders in the directory and how would it compare relative paths? I have managed to do what I wanted with files from the directory, but not folders, and I have no idea how to compare relative paths, even though I searched around I couldn't find it.

So far I've done this script (with help from SO):

```
#!/bin/bash

cd "$1"

function check {
for i in *; do
    if [[-d "$i"]]; then
        cd "$i"
        check
        cd -
    fi

    if [[-f "$i"]]; then
        if [[stat %y "$i" == "$3"]]; then
            #if [[path check]];then
                #touch -r "$i" "$2/path/$i"
    fi
}
```

and I don't know how to do the [[path check]] which should check if both files have the same relative path (relative to the directories given as arguments).

EDIT:

As the answer suggests, is the following code the right way to do it?

```
#!/bin/bash

cd "$1"
shopt -s globstar

for i in **; do

    if [[stat %y "$i" == "$3"]]; then
        if [["$1/$i" == "$2/$i"]];then
            touch -r "$i" "$2/$i"
    fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an answer here before, which I wanted to reply to, suggesting using `shopt -s globstar` and `**` instead of `*`.

The additional question was something along the lines of "Would I be able to compare the relative paths?".

Yes, you would. With `shopt -s globstar`, `**` expands to include the relative path to each file. So it would return `text.txt folder1/secondfile.txt folder2/thirdfile.txt`.

---

EDIT:

You should not need to cd "$1" either, for "$1" and "$2" would not exist inside dir "$1". Try something along the lines of:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
shopt -s globstar

for i in $(cd "$1"; echo **); do
    if [[ $(stat -c %y "$1/$i") == "$3" ]]; then
        if [[ -f "$1/$i" ]] && [[ -f "$2/$i" ]]; then
            touch -r "$1/$i" "$2/$i"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you! I am a bit confused as to how the ** works. That means I don't have to check if the file is a file or a directory anymore I guess, so in my case it would just check if the file found has the same relative path by comparing $1/$i to $2/$i , right?

Comment: Correct. You would not need to recurse into "check", because `**` does that for you.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to take a look at the snippet I am going to add to the original post? Just in case I screw something up. I will do it in a second. edit- done

Comment: The loop would now work. The `stat` call needs a `-c`. The file will need an extra `fi` and a `done` at the end. But the general gist seems correct to me.

Comment: Thank you very much :) !